# google visualization chart, size in percentage

Tags: google-visualization

How do you set the size of a google chart in percentage :
I have this in the html:

```html
<div id="chart_div" width="90%" height="20%"></div>
```

and no width nor height in the options in the js.

But the chart size doesn't adapt to the viewport.

Answer (score 33):

First, use styles to set your dimensions, not attributes:

```html
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 90%; height: 20%;"></div>
```

The chart will draw to the size of the div by default, but the charts are not responsive.  You have to hook a "resize" event handler to the window (or other element if you are resizing within a window) that redraws the chart:

```js
function resizeChart () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
if (document.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeChart);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', resizeChart);
}
else {
    window.resize = resizeChart;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

By multiplying with appropriate factor to $(window).width() or $(window).height() in the chart options

```js
var options = {
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()*0.75
};
```

Comment: That was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Google recommend that you style, like the answer above, with correct CSS and this makes a less-glitchy Chart.
However, you can size it up in Javascript...
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart
So, for the options when you draw the chart (using `chart.draw(data, options)` as above)...

```
var options = {
    width:400,
    height:300
}
```

A good fiddle for a responsive design is here...
http://jsfiddle.net/toddlevy/pyAz5/

Comment: Nice example [themrflibble](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2912215/themrflibble), if you don't want jQuery just use plain JavaScript: 'window.onresize = function(event) { }' . [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblenton/pyAz5/241/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    var container = document.getElementById("chart_div").firstChild.firstChild;
    container.style.width = "100%";

    chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual size of the element, and instead set the height/width of the chart to 500px each manually by adding those to your options:

```
options = {   title: 'My Daily Activities'  
,chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%"}   ,height: 500  
,width: 500 };
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Remove the  width and the height properties from the options in the scripts and  then add the following style to your page

```
<style>
    .chart {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 450px;
    }

    .row {
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
```